# File changes while written to a folder

Tags: python, binary, jpeg, hex-editors

I am working with binary files. They are jpeg images.
I need to edit them with Python and save them.
I've been using this script, and seemed to work fine so far:

```
import os, sys

newpath= r'C:/Users/Umberto/Desktop/temporary'
if not os.path.exists (newpath):
    os.makedirs (newpath)

data= open ('C:/Users/Umberto/Desktop/Prove_Script/Varie/_BR_Browse.001_2065642654_1.BINARY', 'rb+')
edit_data= str (data.read () )
out= open (newpath+ '/preview.BINARY', 'w')

# do my edits in a secon time...

out.write (edit_data)
data.close ()
out.close ()
```

Anyway, a problem (out of Python) arised: my two files are supposed to be the same, but they are not! By opening'em in a hex editor they look slightly different (the original is lower in size than the new one, namely 163 KB, agaist 167).
Moreover, when I open them they ARE different. They are still viewed as images, but one looks fine (the original) while the other is totally a mess...
What went wrong? Is the code I am using changing something that I don't know, and, if so, what?
I hope You could help me.

Comment: Why do you expect the two files to be the same? You're opening a file, drastically changing it, and then saving it - of course it will be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what you're doing in

> `# do my edits in a secon time...`

but that aside, the line

```
edit_data= str (data.read () )
```

will quite drastically change your data. You're opening a binary file, converting the contents to a string, and then saving the contents to a different file, this *will* change things.

```
edit_data = data.read()
```

Changing to above will fix the snippet that you've provided, but if you're editing the data elsewhere this *will* also change things.

**Suggestion**

If you're going to be editing binary files a lot, it might be a good idea to use the `with` syntax

```
with open(my_file, 'rb+') as fo:
    edit_data = fo.read()
```

and then you don't have to worry about closing the file and so on. Once you have `edit_data`, this will be an array of bytes that you can edit in place before saving your data again

```
with open(my_out_file, 'wb') as fo:
    fo.write(edit_data)
```

much cleaner and simpler!

Comment: Thanks for pointing. The comment about the editing means I'm not doing anything actually, just try to write the original file to a folder. Anyway, I thought to convert it to string as it would be much easier for me to edit it, a I am new to programming staff. Your method gives me the right result, so thanks, I'm guessing now if I can edit these binary files as easy as I would edit strings, but I'll try to manage it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Use binary mode:

```
open (newpath+ '/preview.BINARY', 'wb')
```